# Selecting grid squares (polygons) that intersect with a raster

Tags: raster, vector-grid, select-by-location

I have a raster dataset that I have exported a subset from using attribute values (so the extract has areas where there are no pixels). I also have a fishnet grid (polygons) and I want to select the grid squares that contain the extracted raster.  The grid is way bigger than the pixel size of the raster (see image below - brown is the raster, the grid is polygon). Is it at all possible to select polygons (grids) that contain the extracted raster?
[image: brown is the raster - the fishnet is polygon]

Comment: What software are you using? any truly useful answer would have to be tailored to your nominated software. You could create an extent polygon from the raster using its x min/max and y min/max and use that to select the grid squares.

Comment: ArcGIS Pro or QGIS

Comment: Set your geoprocessing output extent https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/environment-settings/output-extent.htm then use Copy Features https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/copy-features.htm to export only the tiles that cover the raster extent; if you are not after creating a new feature class then dissolve (or not, the next step is quicker if you do) the output copied features then use select by location with the dissolved output features as your selecting polygon.